# Tensorflow accuracy from model.predict does not match final epoch val_accuracy of model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, prediction

I am trying to match the accuracy of a model.predict call to the final val_accuracy of model.fit().  I am using tf dataset.

```
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'my_path',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=38,
    image_size=(SIZE,SIZE),
)
```

The dataset setup for train_ds is similar.  I prefetch both...

```
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

Than I get the labels for the val_ds so I can use them later

```
true_categories = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)
```

My model

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 3))
# ... some other layers
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense( len(CLASS_NAMES), activation = tf.keras.activations.softmax)(intermediate)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Compiles fine

```
model.compile(
  optimizer = 'adam', 
  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
  metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Seems to fit fine

```
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=10, 
  class_weight=class_weights) #i do weight the classes due to imbalance
```

The last epoch output

> Epoch 10: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.92291
> 176/176 [==============================] - 191s 1s/step - loss: 0.9876 - accuracy: 0.7318 - val_loss: 0.4650 - val_accuracy: 0.8580

Now I want to verify the val_accuracy == 0.8580 when I run model.predict()

```
predictions = model.predict(val_ds, verbose=2 ) 
flattened_predictions =  predictions.argmax(axis=1)
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(true_categories, flattened_predictions)
print ("Accuracy = ", accuracy)
```

> Accuracy =  0.7980014275517487

I would have expected that to equal the last val accuracy, which was 0.8580, but it is off.  My val_ds uses a seed so I should be getting the images in the same order when I shuffle, right?  Getting ground truth labels is a pain using datasets, but I think (???) my method is correct.

I only have two classes and when I look at my predictions variable it looks like I am getting probabilities as I would expect, so I think I set up, compiled and fit my model correctly for sparse categorical cross entropy using softmax on my final layer output.

```
predictions[:3] #show the first 3 predictions, the values sum to 1.0 as expected
```

> array([[0.42447385, 0.5755262 ],
> [0.2162129 , 0.7837871 ],
> [0.31917858, 0.6808214 ]], dtype=float32)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is that your validation dataset is shuffled at every iteration.

`tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` has `shuffle=True` by default. And that `shuffle` method for a TensorFlow dataset has an argument `reshuffle_each_iteration` which is `None` by default. Therefore it is shuffled everytime.

The `seed=38` parameter is used for tracking the samples that reserved for training and validation separately. In other words, with `seed` argument we can follow which samples will be used for validation dataset and vice versa.

As an example:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(6)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(6, reshuffle_each_iteration=None, seed=154).batch(2)

print("First time iteration:")
for x in dataset:
    print(x)
print("\n")

print("Second time iteration")  
for x in dataset:
    print(x)
```

This will print:

```
First time iteration:
tf.Tensor([2 1], shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([3 0], shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 4], shape=(2,), dtype=int64)


Second time iteration
tf.Tensor([4 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([0 5], shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([2 1], shape=(2,), dtype=int64)
```

Relevant source code for `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py#L211-L214).

If you want to match predictions with their respective labels, then you can loop over the dataset:

```
predictions = []
labels = []
for x, y in val_ds:
    predictions.append(np.argmax(model(x), axis=-1))
    labels.append(y.numpy())

predictions = np.concatenate(predictions, axis=0)
labels = np.concatenate(labels, axis=0)
```

Then you can check accuracy.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  Then how do you use get labels to use with model.predict() when using a tf dataset?

Comment: If you are willing to use `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` you need to set `shuffle=False` or loop over the dataset while collecting both predictions and labels. Otherwise if you build the tf.dataset by yourself then you can use `model.predict()` if you set `reshuffle_each_iteration=False` when using `shuffle()` method.

Comment: Thank you.  To make my code work I simply set `shuffle=False` when setting up my validation dataset.

Comment: Oops.  I don't think that really worked either because now my val_ds, without the shuffle,  looks like it is all of one class.  I might have to build the tf.dataset by myself as you'd mentioned.

Comment: It should have actually, can you confirm it with `np.unique()`? Also I made a mistake in the loop part, I'll fix it and you can also try that.

Comment: Well I left `shuffle = True` for the training set and set `shuffle = False` for the validation.  I'm thinking image_dataset_from_directory then gives me a nicely shuffled training set and a block of one class to for validate.  It does solve my initial problem because when I run model_predict(val_ds) it looks like I get the same validation dataset in the same order as my last model.fit() epoch, but the   for the validation set is all one class.  I confirmed with `confusion_matrix()` ==>  `[[  0,   0],
[640, 761]]>`

Comment: Apologies, the answer I posted (suggesting that class_weight affected the accuracy metric during training) was incorrect, and I'm now voting to delete it. I'm not sure if I can unilaterally delete it. Thanks to @honkskillet for pointing this out.